# Pproblem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):

Tags: python-2.7

so I am using **Pycharm 2019.2** with **Python 2.7**
 and I can't download any package.

I have tried:

- hard copying packages to Python2.7 directory
- pip install urllib3[secure]
- pip install --trusted-host=pypi.python.org --trusted-host=pypi.org
  --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org xlrd

all refused to connect with errors like this:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/xlrd/
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py2.7.egg\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:150: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

in Pycharm, I am getting the following error when trying to install a package:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/geopy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/geopy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:499: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping

Proposed Solution:
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Python27\python.exe'.
```

Everything is working perfectly fine suing python 3.4 but only with 2.7 I'm getting SSL error.
     I can't change to 3.4 due to technical reasons at my workplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an Interpreter Issue. The code was originally written using python 3.7